# Characteristic polynomial of a matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $A\in M_n(F)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $F$ is a finite field. Also suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is irreducible and is equal to its minimal polynomial. If $B\in P[A]$, then is there any relation between characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What is $\;P[A]\;$ ??

Comment: $P[A]=\{a_0I_n+a_1A+\dots+a_nA^n|a_i\in F\}$

Comment: The characteristic polynomial doesn't change if we go to the algebraic closure of the field $\overline{F}$. Working on $M_n(\overline{F})$ we can let $Q\in M_n(\overline{F})$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is in Jordan form. Then $Q^{-1}P(A)Q=P(Q^{-1}AQ)$. But a polynomial $P$ evaluated in a Jordan block with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is still upper triangular and has eigenvalue $P(\lambda_i)$. So, the characteristic polynomial of $B=P(A)$ is $det(P(A)-\lambda I)=det(Q^{-1}P(A)Q-\lambda I)=det(P(Q^{-1}AQ)-\lambda I)$ is equal to the product of $(P(\lambda_i)-\lambda)$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of$A$.

Comment: Each factor taken with the multiplicity they had in $A$.

Comment: @Alamos, Thanks. So always the characterestic polynomial of $A$ and $P(A)$ are equal?

Comment: @maryam It is the polynomial you obtain by replacing the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ by the roots applied to $P$. For example, if $(2-\lambda)^2(3-\lambda)^5$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $(P(2)-\lambda)^2(P(3)-\lambda)^5$.

Comment: @Alamos. Yes you are right. Thanks. If the characteristic polynomial is irreducible for example $\lambda^2+1$ in field $F_3$, then your proof works?

Comment: @maryam The irreducibility is irrelevant, since after going to the algebraic closure the polynomial splits anyway.

Comment: @Alamos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alamos is right. Yet, using $\chi_A$, $\chi_B$ can be calculated without knowing the $(\lambda_i)$. For instance, let $\chi_A(x)=x^4+3x^3-6x^2+2x-1$ and $B=P(A)=A^3-7A^2+3A-I$ (note that we may assume that $\deg(P)\leq 3$). Then $I,B,B^2,B^3,B^4$ are known polynomials in $A$ of degree $\leq 3$. Consequently they are linearly dependent and we deduce explicitly $\chi_B$. We obtain $\chi_B(y)=y^4+247y^3+1189y^2-1023y+487$. If you have Maple, then, using Grobner basis theory, you can automate the calculation.

EDIT. I give some details to my downvoter. We assume that $K$ is a field, $A\in M_n(K)$ and $B=P(A)$ where $P\in K[x]$.

STEP 1. We write $\chi_A(x)=f_1\cdots f_k$ where the $(f_k)$ are irreducible  non-necessarily distinct-. We apply the above method to each $f_i(x)=\Pi (x-\lambda_j)$ and we obtain $g_i(y)$, that is, in general $\Pi (y-P(\lambda_j))$.

STEP 2. If $deg(g_i)=deg(f_i)$, then we are done; otherwise let $deg(f_i)=p$ and $(\lambda_j)$ be the -conjugate over $K$- zeroes of$f_i$. Necessarily $P(\lambda_1)=\cdots =P(\lambda_p)=\alpha \in K$ and $g_i(y)=y-\alpha$ (why ?). Finally, the polynomial that we associate to $f_i$ is $(y-\alpha) ^p$.

STEP 3. $\chi_B$, the characteristic poynomial of $B$, is the product of the polynomials associated to the $f_i$.

Example: $K=\mathbb{R},\chi_A(x)=x^2+x+1,P(x)=x^3$. Then $f_1(x)=x^2+x+1, g_1(y)=y-1$ and $\chi_B(y)=(y-1)^2$.

Comment: Somebody downvoted my post without giving his name or giving explanation. If you do not understand, then ask me. Thus, you will make progress.